# Need help with thinking about design to build bidding service

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, real-time

I have a legacy service written in a procedural style which I am rewriting. I
want to improve the maintainability first and foremost; the code gets tweaked
often as the business rules change over time. Hence, I want to decouple a lot of
things, encapsulate as much of the logic in their own objects as possible, and
make it much easier to test.

I'm looking for help in how to think about the top-level design so as to make those kinds of improvements.

#### Current Service Description

The service basically matches up items and bidders. It does this dozens of times
per minute. As a result, the availability of both items and bidders is rapidly
changing during the process.

Constraints

- There may be 1 to N of match-making processes running simultaneously (N
  currently less than 50, but we want to grow the business).
- Each match-making "run" must complete in less than 1 second.
- There could be tens of thousands of potential items to select from (not all
  will qualify at any given point, usually much closer to a thousand for
  example).
- There may be up to hundreds of bidders.
- Once an item has been "won" it is removed from further consideration until it
  is restocked at some future point.
- Bidders have various limitations on how many items they can bid upon, so there
  is some significant logic required to properly qualify bidders on each item.

#### Procedural Outline

As a result of the above constraints, the current procedural code looks
something like this outline:

1. Grab and reserve a 100 potential *items* out of the database.
2. Loop through the list of 100 *items* looking for cached *items*. (Items with matching bidders were cached after full evaluation as seen below.)

   a. If cached *item* found, **send** to `bidder`, release entire working set
   back to database. DONE.  (Future improvement, evaluate *items* still in
   reserved list to build future cache.)

   b. If no cached item found, continue.
3. Loop through list of *items*, fully evaluating item and bidders:

   a. Is *item* still available? If no, next item. (go to 3)

   b. Else, get list of pre-qualified `bidders`.
4. Are there pre-qualified `bidders`?

   a. No. Loop through "related *items*" linked to initial item, and look for
   pre-qualified `bidders` for each of them. Fall through when complete.

   b. Yes. Loop through `list` of pre-qualified `bidders`.
5. Does pre-qualified bidder have current contract info?

   a. No. Remove from `bidder list`.

   b. Yes, next `bidder`.

At this point we have an *item* and a list (potentially zero in length)
of `bidders`
who can receive the item. There are few final checks to make to fully qualify
the `bidder`.

Remember that we are still within the large loop which started at (2) above
looping through the reserved, working set of 100 potential *items*.

6. If there are `bidders` remaining in the pre-qualified `bidders list`,
   **send** the *item* to those `bidders` for their final approval.

   a. Continue through rest of *item list*, and **cache** any further successful
   matches with `bidders`.

   b. If any remaining final checks fail, **send** that status in place of the
   actual item.
7. When all *items* in *item list* have been examined, release the database
   reservation.

#### Thoughts

What has made this difficult to think about and encapsulate for me is the
multiple places where behavior can change significantly in the middle of looping
through the working set. The original code had statements to break out of
multiple levels of loops within loops. It's been modified a bit to use a pair of
flags indicating state, but it's still pretty convoluted.

Because it has to be fast, and the time before data becomes out of date is
short, figuring out how to encapsulate and decouple this has been hard for me to think about.

#### Edit to Add

In response to good questions below:

- The loop process is kicked off by a human clicking in a web page.  It's the "I'm ready for the next transaction I must manage" indicator.  So the loop is really a way to manage finding the next transaction for each user.
- The 100 record reservation is a tunable, arrived at by testing other values. Approximately 100 gives the best performance as defined by the least amount of wall clock time to return a matching item and bid to the person involved.

One can imagine the people as auctioneers, or as sales people, in that they take the item and finalize the sale arrangement.  They must verbally speak with the item seller to confirm their details, and also speak with the buyer briefly to confirm the sale in the most significant situation.

The number 50 is a rounded-up number of the maximum number of these salespeople involved at any one time.

Regarding parallelism:  This is a web application, so each of evaluation process is kicked off by a click on a web site by one of those sales people, of which there are usually 2 to 50 (currently).

Comment: "Problem easier, because we know each step of the way of data" -- jessitron, [Functional Principles for object oriented development, Jessica Kerr at Ordina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpyrTkzXeL8).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I'll take a look.  I've done some functional programming, but not a lot.

Comment: Also, edited to remove emphasis on OO design.  I'm all about what works well to meet the constraints and provide ease of future maintenance.

Comment: No engineer can say "use this pattern, it is good for your problem" without a very good look at your codebase, your process, and your skills. Shopping for patterns is a recipe for disaster. **Don't do it.**

Comment: @t-sar  I'm looking for help in *thinking* about how to solve the problem, rather than patterns to solve the problem.  Maybe that's a narrow distinction, but I agree with your sentiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OO is fine for this, as are other approaches. As written, it seems like only two things drive ALL your logic:

- Someone taking an action (bid, retraction, price change, etc.)
- Time (auction ending)

As such there is no need to constantly run a procedural loop (the equivalent of polling) for anything other than time-based stuff like auction expirations, emails for auctions about to end, etc. Everything else can be event-driven based on user actions. If you separate your stateful classes from those that "do stuff" you'll be able to scale horizontally (much) more easily.

Not sure why your forebears over-complicated this. Or maybe there are elements you've left out and/or I'm not appreciating. If so, I'll try to revise accordingly based on your updates.

This seems like a fun one where you can improve code quality, performance, and scalability. Good luck and have fun!

**Idea to Explore:**
One process adds items to be "managed" to a queue. User-initiated process pulls items from the queue to be "managed." This should let you scale out the time-bound logic more easily.

Comment: For what it's worth, the loop is not polling, but I see your point.  As I added in response to other questions/remarks, the loop process is kicked off by a human clicking in a web page.  It's the "I'm ready for the next transaction I must manage" indicator.  So the loop is really a way to manage finding the next transaction for each user.  Will add to main description.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you call the person who "manages" these "transactions?" What exactly is a "transaction" in this context--a completed auction or something else? How does an auction end--highest bidder at expiration time or something else?

Separately, can you add "to be managed" auctions to a queue? if not, why not? Assuming it needs to be as complicated as described (not sure of this, btw) then you can factor this into two pieces: [1] adding auctions to the management queue and [2] pulling items to be managed from the queue.

Comment: Failed to tag @CXJ in the above for visibility.

Comment: a transaction in this context is the process from clicking the web app button to being available (done, free) to click the button again.  The person doing that is a customer service rep.  Their management activity involves speaking to the seller to confirm their details and speaking to the bidder to finalize the process.  The auction ends when automatically when the bidder receives the item, so to speak.  The system handles all of the matching, expiration, etc. Adding/removing auctions is all external to this service I'm rewriting. Hope this clear.

Comment: @CXJ Ok, and in what way is the queue idea insufficient to your needs?

Comment: I _think_ the problem with queuing up items is that their status as usable changes rapidly, and if the item is in the queue for more than about 3 seconds, it may actually be unusable when the user-initiated process tries to pull it.  But maybe that's not bad, if the pull is smart enough to just pull another until it gets a good one.  I'll have to think about that.

Comment: @CXJ Sounds like a type of auction I'm unfamiliar with. What non-user initiated events other than start time and expiration time result in changes to the status of an item?

Comment: When you put it that way, I don't think there are any.  The item gets created, and scheduled for auction.  The service rep user initiates a search for a scheduled auction, gets one of those available for this "segment" of time, and contacts the user and the system-matched buyer.  Once sale is finalized, user repeats search.  If there were no matched buyers for some reason, the item gets rescheduled for some future date.  So, based on your very insightful question, really the status only changes by passage of time and by user-initiated events.  Thanks for stating it that way!

Comment: @CJX Glad you found it helpful. Sounds like when auctions end they either go into the "follow-up by customer service rep" pile or the "candidate to reschedule" pile. Customer service reps can just pull oldest from the former. Seems like you can simplify the logic considerably and add horizontal scaling at the same time--very nice!

Comment: I think maybe the confounding problem is this:  a queue is usually first-in, first-out (FIFO).  But the queue of items is constantly added to "randomly" by sellers.  And the auction business does prioritize auctioning of items which have better profit, and also re-prioritizes items based on bidder behavior as well (rescheduling).  So it's as if the sequential order in a FIFO were rearranged every few seconds, and then we tried to pop items off the end without deadlock or race conditions between the reps popping them and the process rearranging them.  The queue of active items is maybe 10-20k.

Comment: @CJX The queue mentioned above contains only completed auctions. In what way would something other than FIFO be needed for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good application for applying OO.  Whether it is or not, I don't think you'll get a lot of assistance with top-level OO design patterns.

The existing system is super complicated, with parallelism and complex logic, and has evolved into an approach that probably no one fully understands: 100 records are grabbed & locked — why 100?  50 parallel matching jobs doing this grabbing — why 50?  Cached records preferred over non-cached (not exactly a business rule).

I assert that you will not be able to replicate the existing system behavior starting with a new top-level design, which would probably be the fullest / most complete way to apply OO.

Does anyone know whether the system would do a better job of matching with different parameters?  What kind of tests do you have for quality of matching?  If none, I'd work on that first and foremost.  Are you leaving better matches on the table due to the performance constraints?  How do we characterize the trade-off in match quality vs. match speed?

Your system has significant parallelism, which OO does not really address.  If you're looking for some kind of replacement, I'd be looking at the overall architecture, especially the parallelism (50 concurrent jobs and the grabs of 100).  I'd ask questions about distributed systems vs. single large memory server to handle the whole load.  If a distributed system is necessary what kind of sharding can be done to minimize commits and locking between servers?

You are right to focus on top-level design: though rather than having a goal to convert the system to OO, I would seek to both improve the functional quality of results as well non-functional performance aspects, via broad architectural approaches dealing with the above, and testing to verify improvement.  If OO comes along with that, then great — though fundamentally you want an understandable & performant architecture & design (then maybe OO or something else to help implement that).

Comment: The 100 record reservation is a tunable, arrived at by testing other values.  Approximately 100 gives the best performance as defined by the least amount of wall clock time to return a matching item and bid to the person involved.  One can imagine the people as auctioneers, or as sales people, in that they take the item and finalize the sale arrangement.

The number 50 is a rounded-up number of the maximum number of these salespeople involved at any one time.

This is a web application, so each of evaluation process is kicked off by a click on a web site by one of those sales people.